# from.is_valid() returns false

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to save customer entry in my database.
I have created a model form and trying to save it. but its not working.
Where is the problem for this ?

my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my forms.py

```
class CustomerEntryForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'phone', 'email']
```

my views.py

```
def customer_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerEntryForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/entry.html', context)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.customer_entry, name="entry"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),  
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

my template

```
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'entry' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="">Name</label><br>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <label for="">Phone</label><br>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" >
    </div>

    <label for="">Email</label><br>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" >
    </div>

    <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="save">

</form>
```

Comment: Actually, you are not saving the form here, but before that, are you sure that `form.is_valid()` returns false? If yes, could you please print also `form.errors` and `form.cleaned_data` after?

Comment: form.errors <ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: form.cleaned_data {'name': 'asd', 'phone': 'g@g.com'}

Comment: Yes, it is as mentioned below, a mistake in Email field name. By the way, you can use usually `form.cleaned` and `form.errors` to investigate what is happening. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that information was indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending email field nor its value to your form

```
   <label for="">Email</label><br>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" >
    </div>
```

as you can see `name="phone"` should be `name="email"` instead